# Alert for no file uploaded to S3 within a particular time

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Python lambda function which gets executed as soon as a .zip file lands in a particular folder in an s3 bucket. Now there may be a situation where there is no file uploaded to the S3 within in a certain time period (for example 10 AM morning). How to get an alert for tracking no file arrival?

Answer (score 1):

You may use cloudwatch alarms. You can set an alarm  when no event (e.g. lambda execution) is present for metrics.

It has only basic options to configure, but imho it's the simplest solution

Comment: Interesting idea! I guess it would be an alarm based on the number of executions of the Lambda function over a period of time (eg past 60 minutes), where the SUM of the count is zero.

Comment: How to setup the alarm? I am new to AWS so don't know much about it.

Comment: In the CloudWatch console, go to Metrics then find the metrics associated with this particular AWS Lambda function. Check the box for the `Invocations` metric, then create an alarm on that metric.